# How to launch the Solr techproducts example on Docker?

Tags: docker, solr

I am running solr in docker and I tried the commands from the comment.

```
docker run --name test -d -p 8983:8983 -t solr
docker exec -it --user=solr test bin/solr create -c techproducts -d sample_techproducts_configs
```

After the last command, I received the following error message:

> Unrecognized argument: example/exampledocs/*.xml .
>
> If this was intended to be a data file, it does not exist relative to /opt/solr

Is this the correct location for the techproducts.xml data?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the official solr image on hub.docker.com and I found this,

```
docker run -d -P -v $PWD/myconfig:/myconfig solr solr-create -c mycore -d /myconfig
```

I guess you need to pass in core configuration from your host with bind mount as in the example. In this case it is not myconfig, it is "sample_techproducts_configs"

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following, it worked for me.

- docker run --name my_solr -d -p 8983:8983 -t solr
- docker exec -it --user=solr my_solr bin/solr create_core -c
  techproducts
- docker exec -it --user=solr my_solr bin/post -c techproducts
  example/exampledocs/